# How to use paginate and display a different alias for the fields in Cake 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I know how to set the aliases for the fields using query builder.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data

I know that there is also another way of using virtual fields

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields

I do not want to use virtual fields.

I want to set aliases for the fields of paginated queries at the controller level on the fly. Similar to how I can set aliases when using the query builder.

How do I accomplish that?

## UPDATE

I am actually using this within Crud plugin.

So the code currently looks like this

```
 $this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(Event $event) use ($conditions) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->paginate['limit'] = 100;
        $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'Events.id', 'Events.title', 'Events.start_date', 
            'Events.end_date', 'Events.revenue', 'Events.total_costs', 'Events.collections'
        ];
    });

    return $this->Crud->execute();
```

## What I have also tried

```
$this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(Event $event) use ($conditions) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->paginate['limit'] = 100;

        $query = $this->Events->find()->select([
            'start' => 'start_date',
            'end' => 'end_date',
            'id', 'title', 'revenue', 'total_costs', 'collections'
        ]);
        $this->paginate($query);
    });
```

## What I got back after trying this

It was as if the select didn't work at all. I got back **all** the fields for `Events`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I accomplish that?

By using a `key => value` syntax in the `fields` option, like

```
$this->paginate = [
    'fields' => [
        'non_aliased_field',
        'alias' => 'field',
        // ...
    ]
];
```

The `fields` option value will be passed to `Query::select()`, so you can use the very same syntax.

Comment: I am using paginate within Crud plugin and I am setting this inside the beforePaginate with an anonymous function. I cannot see how I can directly set the $this->paginate().

Comment: @KimStacks That could have been kind of a different question. Please make sure that you always include such info in your questions. Anyhow, I misinterpreted your problem initially, all you need is to use the same syntax as for `Query::select()` in your `fields` option. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I apologise. It was late night when I was trying to do this. No excuses though for bad questions

Comment: Okay this works, but it prompted another problem I now have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35972918/how-to-set-aliases-and-then-still-affect-the-return-type-for-queries-in-json-for