# How to set aliases and then still affect the return type for queries in json formats for Cake 3.x?

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

## Situation

Using cake 3.2.4

and the plugin Crud 4.2

for the purpose of producing an API feed

## What code did I use at first?

```
  $this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(Event $event) use ($conditions) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->paginate['limit'] = 100;
        $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'id', 'title', 
             'start_date', 
            'end_date', 
            'revenue', 
            'total_costs', 'collections'
        ];
    });
```

## What am I getting as json feed?

```
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 789,
        "title": "9143 - Asia Summit",
        "start_date": "2016-03-02T09:00:00+0800",
        "end_date": "2016-03-04T18:45:00+0800",
        "revenue": 1000000.00,
        "total_costs": 0,
        "collections": 50000.00
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "title": "9144 - 10th  Exhibition",
        "start_date": "2016-03-21T09:00:00+0800",
        "end_date": "2016-03-23T17:00:00+0800",
        "revenue": 2000000.00,
        "total_costs": 0,
        "collections": 50000.00
    }]}
```

## What did I then do?

I wanted to return as aliases so I did the following

```
  $this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(Event $event) use ($conditions) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->paginate['limit'] = 100;
        $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'id', 'title', 
            'start' => 'start_date', 
            'end' => 'end_date', 
            'revenue', 
            'costs' => 'total_costs', 'collections'
        ];
    });
```

## What did I now get?

```
{
"success": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 789,
        "title": "9143 - Asia Summit",
        "start": "2016-03-02 09:00:00",
        "end": "2016-03-04 18:45:00",
        "revenue": 1000000.00,
        "costs": "0.00",
        "collections": 50000.00
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "title": "9144 - 10th Exhibition",
        "start": "2016-03-21 09:00:00",
        "end": "2016-03-23 17:00:00",
        "revenue": 2000000.00,
        "costs": "0.00",
        "collections": 50000.00
    },
```

## So what's wrong?

I get the aliases I wanted, but then the costs has now become a string.

The datetime no longer shows the timezone.

How do I force the fields of the objects in the json feed to be of a certain type whilst keeping the aliases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650306/cakephp-3-x-alias-changing-the-data-type-in-find-method/35652166#35652166 I have no experience with the CRUD plugin however, so I don't know how to access the query object.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment plus http://crud-view.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-usage.html?highlight=query#providing-associations-to-be-displayed helped me find the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Realise that in 3.2 you can use addDefaultTypes to affect the query directly

See [Cakephp-3.x: How to change the data type of a selected alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650306/cakephp-3-x-alias-changing-the-data-type-in-find-method/35652166#35652166)

## Realise that you can access the query from $event when using Crud

See http://crud-view.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-usage.html?highlight=query#providing-associations-to-be-displayed

## Use the types datetime, and decimal

Put it altogther and you get:

```
$this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(Event $event) use ($conditions) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
        $this->paginate['limit'] = 100;
        $this->paginate['fields'] = [
            'id', 'title', 
            'start' => 'start_date', 
            'end' => 'end_date', 
            'revenue', 
            'costs' => 'total_costs', 'collections'
        ];
        $paginationQuery  = $event->subject()->query;

        $paginationQuery
        ->selectTypeMap()
        ->addDefaults([
            'start' => 'datetime',
            'end' => 'datetime',
            'costs' => 'decimal'
        ]);

    });
```